# How do I pass a function with arguments to another function to be called?

Tags: javascript, function, arguments, iteration, object-literal

To be specific, I have one function that iterates through an object literal:

```
    forEachIn: function(objList, action) {
        for (var thing in objList) {
            if (objList.hasOwnProperty(thing)) {
                action(objList[thing]);
            }
        }
    },
```

But the `action` that's being called on each of the property requires another argument, `animations`:

```
    initEquipAnimation: function(equipment, animations) {
        if (typeof equipment !== 'undefined' &&
            equipment !== null) {
            if (equipment.setAnimation) {
                console.log("Setting animation for: " + equipment);
                equipment.setAnimation(animations)
            }
        }
    },
```

How would I go about passing that second argument, without having to edit the `forEachIn` function?  Or should I do something like, pass the possible arguments or parameters in another object or array after `action` in the parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A third argument might be simplest. If you don't want to use that, one possibility is to pass a function of one argument that then invokes the two-argument action method.

```
forEachIn(
    objectList,
    function(equipment) { initEquipAnimations(equipment, animations); }
);
```

This creates a closure assuming that `animations` is set to the animations to be used. Note that if `animations` might vary during the iteration, you might need to create another closure to capture the value using an IIFE:

```
forEachIn(
    objectList,
    (function(anims) {
        return function(equipment) { initEquipAnimations(equipment, anims); }
    }(animations))
);
```

Another possibility is, if you have the flexibility of reordering the arguments to `initEquipAnimation`, is to bind the function to the leading arguments, leaving only the equipment to be supplied by the `forEachIn` iteration.

```
initEquipAnimation : function(animations, equipment) { . . . }

forEachIn(objectList, initEquipAnimation.bind(null, animations));
```

Comment: Ah!  Your first method is going to work for me.  `animations` will be set and will not change throughout the iteration, so it'll be fine.

Comment: (Stack Overflow was not allowing me to edit my comment...)

I did go on to read about Immediately Invoked Function Expressions.  That's going to come in handy for me in the future, I'm sure.  Thanks again!